# MySQL update to other tables

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I want to be able to insert data into `t1` and have data get populated in table `t2` with the primary key as a foreign key in `t2`.

Basically, how come in my current setup when I `INSERT INTO t1 (first_name, last_name) values ( "blah", "blah");`  and then do `SELECT * FROM t2;` `t2` it says `Empty Set (0.00 sec)` for `t2`? Shouldn't it at least show the default `id` of 1?

`t1`:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| first_name | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`t2`:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| address   | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| last_name | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: you have no foreign key requirement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a relational database, a FOREIGN KEY is a declaration that you intend to insert values into T2 that must match an already existing value in T1, and that you want the database to refuse to perform any action that would break this relationship.

It does not mean that the database will create records on its own in order to satisfy a relationship.  If you try to insert a value into T2 that does not exist in T1, the command will fail; it will not add the required record to T1.

That is the opposite of what you're suggesting, however, in which you want the *foreign key* values to get automatically generated.  However, there's no requirement that a primary key value actually *have* references and, furthermore, no limit on the number of times that primary key value can be referenced — so how would the database guess what should be created in T2?

That said, if you want some of your own code to execute automatically when data is added to T1, code which can do whatever you want, you can create a *trigger* on T1.

Answer (score 1):

No, tables won't propagate automatically. (You can however do it with triggers) You will have to insert into `t2`.

Comment: foreign keys are used for referential integrity.

Comment: Not true - what about if you use a trigger?

Comment: @AdrianCornish that requires writing a trigger - its not something that is out of the box.

Comment: I'll go half way :-) you change your answer to say that you cant do it without triggers and I'll pull the -1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on table t1 so that it inserts a row into t2 with the correct id and the other fields NULL

Foreign keys will not insert records for you.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_addr_rec BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t2 SET id=NEW.id, last_name=NEW.last_name
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

*NB untested code*